# iTunes frozen and no activity on my iPad

Tags: windows-7, itunes, ipad

Today I connected my iPad 2 to my PC. iTunes launched and asked if I was happy to upgrade to the latest version of the software. I pressed Yes.

Twenty minutes later, I got a message that the upgrade failed. My iPad had a blank screen without any activity.

Every time I connect the iPad to iTunes now, the following message appears:

> iTunes has detected an iPad in recovery mode. You must restore this
>   iPad before it can be used with iTunes.

I press OK but nothing happens; my iPad is still dead! How can I fix this?

Comment: Perform a hard reset of the iPad. Hold down the Home button and the power button until it resets. You will probably see the iTunes connection image when it restarts. At that stage, perform a factory reset and do a restore from your last backup.

Answer (score 0):

Perform a hard reset of the iPad. Hold down the Home button and the power button until it resets. You will probably see the iTunes connection image when it restarts.

At that stage, perform a factory reset and do a restore from your last backup.